# data-content-id not grabbing content

Tags: html

I´ve this script and want to get the informations out of an data-content-id:

```
$('.hasTooltip').each(function() { // Notice the .each() loop, discussed below
$(this).qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('#tooltip-content-' + $(this).data('contentId')) // Grab  
    content using data-content-id attribite value
    }
});
```

});

I´ve tried the following html code, but the content didn´t get grabbed.

```
<div class="pageContent" data-contentid="test">CONTENTEXAMPLE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute to `data-content-id`. Or use `$(this).data('contentid')`.

EDIT:

> Thats the whole div i´m using: <div class="hasTooltip">Hover me to see
>   a tooltip</div> <div class="pageContent"
>   data-contentid="test">CONTENTEXAMPLE</div>

It's because your `data-contentid` isin't on the `.hasTooltip` element, put the `data-contentid` on the same element that has the `.hasTooltip` class.

Comment: Still get not grabbed. I´ve changed it like so    $(this).data('contentid') and the html:       data-contentid="test"

Comment: @user2800148 How about `$(this).attr('data-contentid')`? If that doesn't work either your problem is something else. Have you tried logging the value of `this` to check what it is? Also, are you sure that the code actually gets applied to your elements? You are selection elements with the `hasToolTip` class but your div doesn't seem to have that class.

Comment: Thats the whole div i´m using:      <div class="hasTooltip">Hover me to see a tooltip</div> <div class="pageContent" data-contentid="test">CONTENTEXAMPLE</div> Even with your change it does not work. :/ What do you mean with logging the value?

Comment: First, thanks for you help. But it doesn´t work. I´ve made this http://jsfiddle.net/L6yq3/465/. There you can see the problem. The content isn´t inside of the tooltip.